# File not found after rename

Tags: ios, xcode

I renamed my project from "Mark2" to "Mark3" in Project Navigator, by clicking Enter on project name. 
When I run it, it failed with this error:

```
 ld: file not found: /Users/Bright/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mark3-amoubbpqbrysrtffmvtagyhxcmcu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mark2.app/Mark2
 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Did you change the app name, exactly like this:
http://matthewfecher.com/app-developement/xcode-tips-the-best-way-to-change-a-project-name-in-xcode/

Comment: I tried, but it still doesn't work

Comment: Did you also change the `Product Name` in the *Build Settings*?

Comment: No, I didn't. It's not written in the tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the app from your simulator and run again.

Follow this tutorial and try again

[Changing App Name](http://matthewfecher.com/app-developement/xcode-tips-the-best-way-to-change-a-project-name-in-xcode/)

Also try this

Clean Build Folder -- Go to the Product Menu in XCode, press the option key -- the "Clean" command

> (Shift + Cmd +K)

changes to "Clean Build Folder"

> (Option+Shift+Command+K)

.
[image: Xcode clean build]

**Edit**:

In your Application's target choose Build Settings and check the name of the product, is it still Mark2.
You can also try restarting your XCode.

Comment: Cleaning and restarting Xcode won't do anything.  The `Product Name` needs to be changed in the *Build Settings*.

Comment: __[OFF]__ taking a 'screenshot' with your phone? uh. why not ⌘+⇧+4? __[ON]__